# How to draw a tiled wall between two points on a grid on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw, pixi.js

I'm creating a simulator with the Pixijs engine.

I have a function that is is to be used to draw a wall using the mouse. But I just can't seem to get it right. This is probably more of a math issue than programming.

Anyway, it should work like this:

- User clicks on a square tile (start position is set)
- Tink library for Pixi returns the (x,y) position just clicked on
  relative to the canvas
- User clicks on second square (in same row or column) and the
  destination point is set

Please take a look at this Fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ensf32e0/18/

I can get it to draw from left to right and from top to bottom. But right to left and bottom to top fail me.
I'm using an object with booleans to keep track of whether the user is putting down a start position or an end position. I'm not sure this isa good implementation.

```
let wallsObj={
  start:{
    x:0,
    y:0,
    done:false
  },
  end:{
    x:1,
    y:1,
    done:false
  }
};
```

drawTile draws a single tile and drawWallLine is the function with the problem. It takes the start and end positions and draws a tiled line between them:

```
function drawWallLine (obj,size) {
    // Determine whether line is to be drawn horizontally or vertically
    // if abs(x2-x1) is larger than abs(y2-y1) then horizontal else vertical
    // assign len the the actual length of line
    let len = Math.abs(obj.end.x - obj.start.x) > Math.abs(obj.end.y - obj.start.y)
        ? obj.end.x - obj.start.x
        : obj.end.y - obj.start.y;
        console.log('drawWallLine', len);

        // same as above. If direction is horizontal, mx = 1 and my = 0 and vice versa
        // this to be used to determine the polarity of size
        let mx = Math.abs(obj.end.x - obj.start.x) > Math.abs(obj.end.y - obj.start.y) ? 1 : 0;
        let my = Math.abs(obj.end.x - obj.start.x) < Math.abs(obj.end.y - obj.start.y) ? 1 : 0;
        console.log("mx, my", mx, my);

        // Get polarity of size. +size is going down or right while -size is going up or left
        if (mx === 1) {
            size = obj.end.x - obj.start.x >= 0 ? size : size * -1;
        }
        if (my === 1) {
            size = obj.end.y- obj.start.y >= 0 ? size : size * -1;
        }

        console.log('size', size);

        // If going down or right then 
        if (size >=0 ) {
            for (let i = 0; i < Math.abs(len); i+=size) {
                drawTile({
                    len: rs,
                    x: obj.start.x - obj.start.x%rs - .5 + i * mx,
                    y: obj.start.y - obj.start.y%rs - .5 + i * my,
                    line:{
                        width:1,
                        color:0xC2C2C2,
                        alpha:1
                    },
                    fill:{
                        color:0xFFFFFF,
                        alpha:1
                    }
                });
            }
        } else { // if going up or left
            for (let i = Math.abs(len); i > 0; i+=size) {
                drawTile({
                    len: rs,
                    x: obj.start.x - obj.start.x%rs - .5 + i * mx,
                    y: obj.start.y - obj.start.y%rs - .5 + i * my,
                    line:{
                        width:1,
                        color:0xC2C2C2,
                        alpha:1
                    },
                    fill:{
                        color:0xFFFFFF,
                        alpha:1
                    }
                });
            }
        }

}
```

This is my first time doing something like this so please bear with me. I feel like there's an obvious solution but i'm failing to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a simple fix to your problem is just to make sure that the start x/y is always the lower then the end x/y value. So I added the following code to the beginning of the *drawWallLin*e function:

```
function drawWallLine (obj, size) {

    if(obj.start.x > obj.end.x){
        var temp = obj.start.x;
      obj.start.x = obj.end.x;
      obj.end.x = temp;
    }

    if(obj.start.y > obj.end.y){
        var temp = obj.start.y;
      obj.start.y = obj.end.y;
      obj.end.y = temp;
    }
```

This basically makes sure that the start value is always the lower value by swapping between *start* and *end* if *start* is bigger than *end*.

Here is the updated working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ensf32e0/24/

Comment: Oh ... that makes so much sense. Just swap them. I feel so dumb lol. But thanks ! Your solution works perfectly